# Mongoose DB Lookup pipeline match problem

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collection

Once is User,
Another once is UserBmi

I would planning to join the collection to find the latest BMI records.
In this table, some user would not upload their BMI records. to database.
I would want to return the empty row on the result.
However, the result would return all the user are return the same record (the latest BMI record of one of user).

Would I missing something when I Match the 2 collections?

User Table

```
const userSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    usercardid:{
        type:Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    }... 
})
```

BMI Table

```
const userbmigoriesSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({

    user_id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    user_height:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    user_weight:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    user_bmi:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})
```

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:{
                from: "userbmis",
                let: {"uid": "user_id"},
                pipeline: [{
                    $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$uid","$id" ]}}},
                    {$sort: {"date": -1}},
                    {$limit: 1}
                ],
                as: "userbmis"
            }
        }
    ])
```

[image]
In this image, All the Height , Weight , BMI record are Belong to 3rd User.

= MongooseDB Data
On the image, you can see Row 2 to row 6 BMI records are belongs to
the user 608915308462c0ccec435a97. however, when I lookup the data, each user would getting the same record.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the problem you have?If you want a user that didn't had any BMI records to not appear in the results filter `{"$size" : "$userbmis"} > 0` after the `$lookup`

Comment: Some user would getting incorrect BMI record when lookup the collections. I upload the screenshot of the collection, hope you can understand my problem

Comment: Looks like maybe a typo?  should be `let: {"uid": "$user_id"},` or perhaps `$match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$uid","$_id" ]}}},`

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried your suggestion, however, it does not work too.  When I typo ["$$uid","$_id" ], all user are return the empty array on the userbmis